# postgresql, get list of items with nearest point where condition is true

Tags: postgresql

EDIT: Skip to last edit for current status

Hello !

I have a table with weather stations

stations:

```
id,
point, (geometry(Point,4326))
ctry (country code)
```

And a table with weather data:

noaa:

```
id                 | integer                     | not null    default    nextval('noaa_id_seq'::regclass)
usaf_wban          | text                        |
station_id         | integer                     |
usaf               | integer                     |
wban               | integer                     |
dt                 | timestamp without time zone | not null
point              | geometry(Point,4326)        |
air_temp           | double precision            |
dew_point          | double precision            |
relative_humidity  | double precision            |
sea_level_pressure | double precision            |
pressure           | double precision            |
wind               | double precision            |
cloudiness         | double precision            |
ghi                | double precision            |
```

and another locations_location where i get the point

I've experimented a lot with indexes, current indexes on noaa table are:

```
Indexes:
"noaa_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"noaa_dt_trunc" btree (date_trunc('hour'::text, dt))
"noaa_point" gist (point)
"noaa_station_ids" btree (station_id)
```

**Now i want to select for each param (air_temp, wind ..)
the nearest point where this param is not null and not 9999**

At this moment i use 5 single queries which look like that:

```
 with postal_station AS (
        SELECT id as station_id, s.point FROM stations s WHERE s.ctry = 'AU'
        ORDER BY s.point <-> (
            SELECT point FROM locations_location l
            WHERE l.postal_code = '9201' AND l.country_code = 'AT'
            LIMIT 1
        )
        LIMIT 5
    )
    SELECT
        DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('hour', dt))
        date_trunc('hour', dt) as dt,
        cloudiness
    FROM
        noaa n
    WHERE
        dt BETWEEN '2010-01-01'::timestamp AND '2015-01-01'::timestamp
        AND
        NOT cloudiness = 9999
        AND
        NOT cloudiness is null
        AND
        n.station_id IN (SELECT station_id FROM postal_station)
    ORDER BY dt, point <-> ( SELECT point FROM postal_station LIMIT 1 )
```

which is quite fast ~150ms and the only index getting used is noaa_station_ids

but at the moment i increase the limit for station_ids about 5 :

```
with postal_station AS (
        SELECT id as station_id, s.point FROM stations s WHERE s.ctry = 'AU'
        ORDER BY s.point <-> (
            SELECT point FROM locations_location l
            WHERE l.postal_code = '9201' AND l.country_code = 'AT'
            LIMIT 1
        )
        LIMIT 6
    )
    SELECT
        DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('hour', dt))
        date_trunc('hour', dt) as dt,
        air_temp
    FROM
        noaa n
    WHERE
        dt BETWEEN '2010-01-01'::timestamp AND '2015-01-01'::timestamp
        AND
        NOT air_temp = 9999
        AND
        NOT air_temp is null
        AND
        n.station_id IN (SELECT station_id FROM postal_station)
    ORDER BY dt, point <-> ( SELECT point FROM postal_station LIMIT 1 )
```

https://explain.depesz.com/s/9n2M

the index noaa_station_ids is not getting used anymore and the query takes about ~2429ms

So here are my questions:

- Why is the index noaa_station_ids not used if the "n.station_id IN" clause contains more then 5 values ?
- Is there a way to select all needed values in one query in reasonable time ?

Thank you for reading :)

PS: Postgres 9.5 with postgis enabled

EDIT: actually the cte should look like this to get the correct point for ordering .. but thats a side thing here

```
with postal_point AS (
        SELECT point FROM locations_location l
        WHERE l.postal_code = '9201' AND l.country_code = 'AT'
        LIMIT 1
    ),
    postal_station AS (
        SELECT id as station_id, s.point FROM stations s WHERE s.ctry = 'AU'
        ORDER BY s.point <-> ( SELECT point FROM postal_point )
        LIMIT 5
    )
```

EDIT: After joinen #postgresql on freenode RhodiumToad helped me to build this query

```
with postal_station AS (
        select
            s1.*
        from (
            select point from locations_location l where l.postal_code = '9201' AND l.country_code = 'AT' limit 1
        ) l0,
        lateral (
            select s.id, rank() over (order by s.point <-> l0.point)
            from
            stations s
            where
            s.ctry = 'AU'
        order by s.point <-> l0.point limit 20) s1
    )
    SELECT
        DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('hour', dt))
        date_trunc('hour', dt) as dt,
        air_temp
    FROM
        noaa n
    JOIN
        postal_station p
        ON
        p.id = n.station_id
    WHERE
        dt BETWEEN '2010-01-01'::timestamp AND '2015-01-01'::timestamp
        AND
        NOT air_temp = 9999
        AND
        NOT air_temp is null
    ORDER BY dt, p.rank
```

Which is fast ~200ms even with more stations => https://explain.depesz.com/s/kA8

I will mark this post as answered in a few days.

Optimisation is still welcome.

Comment: Note: the definition for your `noaa table` does not contain the columns `dt` and `station_id`. Please add the *real* table definitions for your table(s) to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) Why is the index noaa_station_ids not used if the "n.station_id IN" clause contains more then 5 values ?

2) Is there a way to select all needed values in one query in reasonable time ?
```

1) after increasing cpu_tuple_cost to 0.1 the index was used also with more stations but the query is still getting slow with higher number of stations

2) atm i use 5 queries and send them at once to get all needed data, together with the query in the last edit the query times are ok.

To the query:

Key was to rank the stations in the cte and then join the cte.
This way sort is much faster.